# Flutter FontLoader: How to specify the font weight and style for the loaded font?

Tags: flutter, fonts

I'm using the FontLoader to download fonts from the server.
FontLoader allows to specify only the font family name, but not the weight and style for the loaded font file.
My concern is that how flutter understand which font file to pick when the font weight and style are specified in the textStyle property.

Let's say I have 6 font files in the server light, normal, bold weights for each normal and italic styles. I'm loading all of them by the FontLoader, but I do not specify which one is what, as FontLoader allows to specify only the font familly name. So how flutter determine which font to use when it needs to display a text with w300 and style:Italic?

Is that weight and style information available in the font file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but I have made a utility for similar usecase.
Check it out, inspired by whatsapp's way of styling, includes;

- Bold, Italic, Strikethrough, Underline, Monospace, Clickable Hyperlinks and Dynamic Font Sizing

https://pub.dev/packages/typeset